# Website not loading on other networks

Tags: permissions

I  have finally set up a domain using Apache and DNS2Go.

However, when i try to run it on other networks (outside LAN), it refuses the connection. Only very few seem to be able to access the website.

Port 80 is completely open and Firewall is not blocking it, yet i still can't access it from outside. I'm hosting this on Windows (Pretty simple). It gives a "refused to establish connection" error.

The URL is [this (click here)](http://orevideos.d2g.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is pretty obvious.

```
$ host orevideos.d2g.com
orevideos.d2g.com has address 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: DNS2Go is the problem, then. I'll try NoIP or something.

Comment: @StarOS I doubt the problem lies with DNS2Go.

Comment: It doesn't, actually. I go to 127.0.0.1 and see the webpage i should have seen. I'll ask a new question regarding how to change it to my IP.